# What is it that Nick did for Gilead?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-handmaids-tale

In Season 3 Episode 6, we see that the Swiss delegates reject Nick as a Gilead's inside man owing to the fact that 'he cannot be trusted' and according to Serena Joy he 'played an instrumental role in the birth of Gilead'.

With the kind of pomp that Nick got from the Swiss and the Waterfords in episode 6, it almost looked like he truly played a very instrumental role in the birthing of Gilead. If he did play such an 'important instrumental' role in the birth of Gilead, what was he doing as Commander Waterfords personal guard?

**What did Nick actually do for Gilead?**

Comment: Judging from what I read online the makers have kept this under wraps for now and only shown that he isn't what he presented himself as (i.e. he was a baddy and not some "victim of circumstances"). Perhaps s4 will go deeper into this.

Comment: I would need to check, before I make an answer/or see if this is enough to answer the Q, but I think I remember something about him being recruited into the Sons of Jacob, which is the group that created the totalitarian patriarchal theocracy philosophy and orchestrated the rise of Gilead...

Comment: @DarthLocke Yes, but that doesn't answer the second part of the question: if Nick was so important, why did he end up in such a lowly position?

Comment: I know. That's why I said, "see if this is enough to answer the Q", because I realized it might not answer the rest of it and I'm not sure if it had been answered yet on the series--wanted to see if the wikis confirmed anything I remember...

Comment: I think he must have done something important not just being a soldier, otherwise, it wouldn't be a big deal for any of the sides. My guess is he was one of the main people who were involved in the initial attacks that brought the Sons of Jacob into power (aka President's Day Massacre).